# Why does Java WatchService keep open filehandles?

Tags: java, windows, filesystemwatcher

Hi so I'm trying to create a java app that notices when a file with a dot (i.e. '.') in front of the name is created so that it can hide it (I'm a windows user). But I've noticed that the watcher service keeps many open filehandles which makes it impossible to move/edit some of my directories and files. I've found no rhyme or reason to the ones that it interferes with (versus leaving alone) so there might be something weirder going on here. But basically I want to know why this is and how to avoid it since it makes the WatcherService almost useless as it is.